# how to access the elements which created using the jquery insertAfter method

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a select tag which when its change I'm showing  another input for the user and when the user change the select tag multiple times the element insert after each other but i want to remove old input after changing the select tag and insert the new related input.

Comment: In future, please include a relevant example of your existing code. In fact, it wouldn't hurt to edit it in to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep track of a reference to the element then...

```
var element;

$("#sel").change(function () {
    var sel = $(this);
    if(element)//check if an input has already been created
        element.remove();//remove the old input from the DOM
    element = $("<input/>").val(sel.val());//create the new input and store the reference
    element.insertAfter(sel);//insert the new input to the DOM
});

$("#sel").change();
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/j6RQP/)

Because `insertAfter` is a function of the element you are creating, you must already be creating a reference to it in your current code anyway. So you just need to store that reference globally. Then each time you change the select, you can check if the reference has a value and remove it from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Put the new elements in a selectable `div` or `span`, and empty the container before creating the new element:

```
$('#inputContainer').empty().append('<input/>');
```